# HP Omen 600 mouse and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, mouse, hp

I'm think of buying https://store.hp.com/UKStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=1KF75AA&opt=ABB&sel=ACC , HP Omen 600 wired mouse for use on Ubuntu 20.04. I've seen reports about mixed compatibility. I'm not bothered about programming buttons on the mouse but if I just plug it in to the USB port should it work fine for the standard functions?
I'm wondering if anyone else has tried an HP gaming wired mouse on modern Ubuntu distros and if they've had success. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the only way of truly knowing is trying. And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse works fine... just plug and play.